# How do i numerate every <h2> in a wordpress post using php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add a number before each  subtitle on specific posts (that has the option "indice" created with acf checked) subsequentially.

I achieved the objective using css:

```
   body { counter-reset: h2counter; } 
h1 { counter-reset: h2counter; } 

h2:before { content: counter(h2counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0"; counter-increment: h2counter; counter-reset: h3counter; } 

h3:before { content: counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0"; counter-increment: h3counter; }
```

But I would like to know if a php counterpart could be made.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  if (have_rows('flexible_field')) {
    $count = 0;
    while (have_rows('flexible_field')) {
      the_row();
      $count++;
      echo '<div>',$count,'</h2>';
    }
  }
?>
```

flexible_field is the name of your field value in custom field, you need to modify according to your back end settings , the above will print counter in h2 tag and than css using your need

Comment: Please could you explain me why this piece of code should work?

Comment: It shouldn't be if get field 'example'.... And endif at the end? also if there is a counter like that I think it should be put in functions.php because the post is printed through the function the_content. So how this code is gonna work?